# Get html table to extend over 100%, but only if needed

Tags: html, css

I'm making this website for a lady and I was thinking that I might have a problem.  It looks like this on my screen, and thats perfect:
[here](http://droemmebilleder.dk/myscreen.jpg)

But I think that the most users for this site may have smaller or older monitors and they will have to scroll down to find the bottom looking like
[this](http://droemmebilleder.dk/smallerscreen.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<table align="center" id="content" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" vspace="0">
<tr align="center" valign="top">

<td rowspan="2" id="pageshadow_left"></td>

<td height="209">
<div style="position:relative; height:100%;">
<img src="textlogo.png" width="387" height="90">
<a href="index.php" target="_self"><div id="forside"><img src="forside.png"></div></a>
<a href="profil.php" target="_self"><div id="profil"><img src="profil.png"></div></a>
<a href="udstillinger.php" target="_self"><div id="udstillinger"><img     src="udstillinger.png"></div></a>
<a href="kurser.php" target="_self"><div id="kurser"><img src="kurser.png"></div></a>
<a href="kontakt.php" target="_self"><div id="kontakt"><img src="kontakt.png"></div></a>
<div id="logotop"></div>
<div id="logofront" align="right"></div>
<div id="velkommen" align="center"></div>
<div id="fronttextwrapper" style="position:relative">
<div id="fronttext" align="left">

<?php echo "PHP Virker!"; ?>

<p>Drømmebilleder kalder jeg mine malerier.
Jeg benytter stilhed, meditation og musik til skabelse af malerierne.
De bliver hovedsageligt skabt intuitivt ud fra mine indre billeder,
og helt naturligt vil disse billeder bl.a. være frugten af oplevelser i naturen,     inspiration fra andre kunstnere, bøger der er læst, film der er set.</p>
<p></p>
<p>Mine malerier har ingen titler, det er bevidst, da det er vigtigere for mig 
hvad du oplever og ikke hvad jeg føler du skal opleve, lad malerierne tale til 
dig og få din personlige  drømmebilled- oplevelse.</p>
<p></p>

<p>Jeg underviser i at male intuitivt, så er du blevet inspireret,
kan du kigge under kurser, Du behøver ikke at have malet før
for at skabe dine egne drømmebilleder.</p>
<p></p>

<p>God fornøjelse med at kigge i galleriet, og måske på gensyn.</p>
<p>Drude</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>


<td rowspan="2" id="pageshadow_right";></td>
</tr>


</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
background-color:#918c8c;
margin:0px;
height:auto;
padding : 0px;  
width : 100%; 
height : 100%; 
overflow:visible;
}

img {
border-style:none;
}

#content {
border-style:none;
background-color:#ffffff;
width:1050px;
height:100%;
margin-top:0px;
background-image:url(top.png);
background-position:top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-bottom:500px;
overflow:visible;
}

#forside {
width:128px;
height:67px;
position:absolute;
top:80px;
left:40px;
}

#profil {
width:146px;
height:68px;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:180px;
}

#udstillinger {
width:188px;
height:61px;
position:absolute;
top:107px;
left:342px;
}

#kurser {
width:118px;
height:51px;
position:absolute;
top:115px;
left:540px;
}

#kontakt {
width:268px;
height:83px;
position:absolute;
top:74px;
left:680px;
}

#logotop {
width:50px;
height:54px;
background-image:url(logotop.png);
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:5px
}

#pageshadow_left {
border-style:none;
width:25px;
background-image:url(page_shadow_left.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#pageshadow_right {
border-style:none;
width:25px;
background-image:url(page_shadow_right.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-y
}

#velkommen {
position:absolute;
top:180px;
left:103px;
background-image:url(velkommen.png);
width:794px;
height:136px;
}

#logofront {
background-image:url(logo.png);
width:200px;
height:241px;
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:760px;
}

#fronttext {
position:absolute;
top:300px;
left:100px;
width:450px;
height:auto;
text-align:left;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:18px;
}

#wrapper {
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Anyone who knows what will do the trick?

Comment: Why are you using a table to do your layout?

Tables should only be used to display tabular data.

Regular html elements should be used for your display such as divs or HTML5 section, header, footer etc.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Hope you'll learn along the way just like we all have..

Comment: Billy, actually I'm using the table because I don't know how to center a div, and because it seemed like the easiest way to add the shadows on the sides. And I don't know the reason for using header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

you can not make a table to 100% height either you can make min-height according to your content height.